# Task needs longer than return

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, return, task

I have a problem. If I call the function, the new Task, which connects to the database, is needing longer than the return, so it will return something weired. I want to make this asynchronous, so i don't want to do it without async. How to fix this, apparently, the "await new Task(() =>" is not working properly.

I originally made this non-async, but this is making me problems.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Security
    {
        public async Task<bool> CheckAccount(string rowrequest_)
        {
            Extract extract = new Extract();
            string password = string.Empty, username = string.Empty, returndata = string.Empty;


            bool x = await new Task<bool>(() => 
            {
                DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection();

                username = extract.ExtractValue(rowrequest_, "username");

                password = extract.ExtractValue(rowrequest_, "password");

                string connectionStr = "frozenfiredb::std@basicconnection~(((dbuser)program(*dbuser)(dbpassword)K%ls!Sfgh3lloW%0rld45(*dbpassword)(dbtable)CasinoUser(*dbtable))(read_content)" + username + "(*read_content))";

                returndata = connection.StaticConnection(connectionStr);

                return !returndata.StartsWith("FILE ERROR") && password == returndata;
            });
            return x;
        }
    }
```

The output is not correct.

Comment: Why are you forcing Async by creating new Task<bool> is there any specific reason?

Comment: There isn't any reason to use `Task` in your code.

Comment: It has to be multi-client.

Comment: The default DataBase timeout is 30 seconds.  If you are getting weird results than you are either getting an error or it is taking a very long time to retrieve data and maybe make the timeout longer.  The issue has nothing to do with the await.

Comment: i have made this database on my own, so there isn't practically any timeout.

Comment: Did you intend to run the task?  You're only constructing the task. You could await `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: Yes, but i need a new Task (`new Task`).

Answer (score 1):

> apparently, the "await new Task(() =>" is not working properly.

You should [never, ever, ever use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Ideally, you should *start* with your lowest-level database APIs and change them to use the `*Async` APIs (with `await`), and then let `async` grow from there. It's difficult to tell where the I/O is in your code sample, but here's one possibility of how that may look:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckAccountAsync(string rowrequest_)
{
  Extract extract = new Extract();
  string password = string.Empty, username = string.Empty, returndata = string.Empty;

  DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection();
  username = extract.ExtractValue(rowrequest_, "username");
  password = extract.ExtractValue(rowrequest_, "password");
  string connectionStr = "frozenfiredb::std@basicconnection~(((dbuser)program(*dbuser)(dbpassword)K%ls!Sfgh3lloW%0rld45(*dbpassword)(dbtable)CasinoUser(*dbtable))(read_content)" + username + "(*read_content))";

  returndata = await connection.StaticConnectionAsync(connectionStr);
  return !returndata.StartsWith("FILE ERROR") && password == returndata;
}
```

If this isn't possible (due to API limitations) or feasible (too much work for now), **and** if your code is in a GUI app (not ASP.NET), then you can keep this method synchronous and just *call* it asynchronously using `Task.Run`:

```
public bool CheckAccount(string rowrequest_)
{
  Extract extract = new Extract();
  string password = string.Empty, username = string.Empty, returndata = string.Empty;

  DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection();
  username = extract.ExtractValue(rowrequest_, "username");
  password = extract.ExtractValue(rowrequest_, "password");
  string connectionStr = "frozenfiredb::std@basicconnection~(((dbuser)program(*dbuser)(dbpassword)K%ls!Sfgh3lloW%0rld45(*dbpassword)(dbtable)CasinoUser(*dbtable))(read_content)" + username + "(*read_content))";

  returndata = connection.StaticConnection(connectionStr);
  return !returndata.StartsWith("FILE ERROR") && password == returndata;
}

...

string rowrequest = ...;
bool result = await Task.Run(() => CheckAccount(rowrequest));
```